# How to know local report path in rdlc report in c#

Tags: c#, rdlc

I want to check which Report is calling in the application.
Means I want to know the local report path of the rdlc.

I am using now:

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportpath;
```

But I'mm getting Error like:

> An Error Occur during Local Report Processing

Comment: provide more about your environment, what's thecontent of reportpath, 
I assume the path should be relative to your appdomain

did you set             reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
?

Answer (score 3):

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourWindowsFormsCSharpProject.ReportsFolder.Report1.rdlc";
```

Comment: The application only works on my computer `reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CV.Report.ReportCv.rdlc`, but when I try it on another computer it does not work . getting **error :An Error Occur during Local Report Processing**

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataset);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Reports/RPT_Reports.rdlc");
```

Comment: check you report parameter